# Meaning of "pax count"

Tags: meaning

I want to know what is pax count regarding to hotel search.
 I want deep meaning of pax count.

Comment: The word is included in [Oxford online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pax) at *pax²* since *pax¹* is obviously irrelevant.

Comment: However, if this is a website asking for the number of people you intend booking for, it's a very poor choice of word: it is jargon.

Answer (score 3):

*pax* is short for [passenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passenger). It's mostly used in the context of transportation, not for hotels, though.